# recorrer un retorno de tipo tabla en plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Buenas recientemente he empezado a estudiar por mi cuenta plpgsql y me surge una duda, si tengo esta función...

```
create or replace function prueba_reg_table (in cat categories.category%type) returns table (catnombre varchar, prodnombre varchar) as $$
begin
    return query
    select c.categoryname, p.title from categories c, products p where c.category = cat and c.category = p.category;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

¿como puedo recorerla mediante un cursor o similar en un bloque? ¿algo así (pero que funcione claro)? :)

```
do language plpgsql $$
declare
    c table;
begin
    for  (select * from prueba_reg_table(1)) loop
        raise notice 'La categoria es % y el titulo %', c.catnombre, p.prodnombre;
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Esto mismo lo he conseguido hacer mediante el retorno de tipo record pero no mediante el retorno de tipo table.

¿Que ventajas tiene este tipo de dato?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ventajas de cada mecanismo la puedes definir tu mismo si te aplican o no

Por ejemplo si defines una funcion de tipo record, la consulta de dentro de la función puede cambiar el resultado sin necesidad de cambiar el tipo de dato, pero para llamar a la funcion debes saber que retorna... sin embargo con el tipo table siempre sabes que viene. puedes ver algunas respuestas a preguntas similares aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423958/sql-function-return-type-table-vs-setof-records

Tambien puedes definir tu tipo de dato y retornarlo